# Ruby: selective class inheritance?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class-method

So, I've been playing with some models, and I've run into a situation where I'd really like to limit the inheritance of a class method by a subclass. Trouble is, my experimentation has so far confirmed my understanding that this cannot be done.

I naïvely tried the following:

```
class Policy
  class << self
    def lookup(object)
      #returns a subclass by analyzing the given object, following a naming convention
    end

    def inherited( sub )
      sub.class_eval { remove_method :lookup }
    end
  end
end
```

Of course that doesn't work because the subclass doesn't have the method, it's on the super class. After that I tried:

```
def inherited( sub )
  class << Policy
    remove_method :lookup
  end
end
```

That works like a charm, haha, except for the tiny detail that it works by taking the method off the superclass the first time a subclass is loaded. Oops!

So, I'm pretty sure this can't work due to the way Ruby looks up methods.

The reason I'm interested is that in the behavior I'm working on you could have many different policies, following a naming convention, and I'd like to have a nice clean way to get a reference to the policy for any other class of object. To me, syntatically, it seems nice to do this:

```
class RecordPolicy < Policy
  # sets policy concerning records,
  # inherits common policy behavior from Policy
end

class Record
end

$> record = Record.new
=> #<Record:0x0000>
$> Policy.lookup(record)
=> RecordPolicy
```

However, I don't think it makes any sense to be able to call `RecordPolicy#lookup`. You've got the policy, there's nothing underneath to find.

**So, my question is two parts:**

1) Is there, in fact, some way to selectively define what class methods can be inherited in Ruby?

At this point I'm pretty much certain the answer to that is no, therefore:

2) Given that I want to encapsulate the logic for inferring a policy name for any given object *somewhere*, and it looks to me like what I've tried so far demonstrates that the Policy class is the *wrong* place for it, where would you put this kind of thing instead?

Thanks!

---

**Update**

Thanks to JimLim for answering part 1, and Linuxios for responding to part 2. Very useful insight from both.

FWIW, after reflecting on what Linuxios said, here is what I decided to do:

```
class << self
  def lookup( record )
    if self.superclass == Policy
      raise "No default naming convention exists for subclasses of Policy. Override self.lookup if you want to use it in a subclass."
    else
      # naming convention lookup goes here
    end
  end
end
```

I feel like this is the least astonishing thing for how this code will be used. If someone has some reason to provide a #lookup method on a subclass, they can set one, but if they call the one that was inherited they get an exception that tells them it doesn't make sense to do so.

As to how to decide who gets the "answer" since they both answered 1/2 of my question, my personal habit in the case of a "tie" has been to accept the answer from the person with less reputation at the time.

Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Would it be a good idea to define a `lookup` method in subclasses that does nothing but perhaps raises an exception?

Comment: undef_method might work.

Comment: @JimLim That strikes me as a viable fallback, but my thought is that other people are going to create subclasses, and I'd rather that from their perspective that one method simply didn't exist when they inherit. Looks like we've got some options in the answers below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`undef_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-undef_method) seems to work. According to the documentation,

> Prevents the current class from responding to calls to the named
>   method. Contrast this with remove_method, which deletes the method
>   from the particular class; Ruby will still search superclasses and
>   mixed-in modules for a possible receiver.

```
class Policy
  def self.lookup(object)
  end
end

class RecordPolicy < Policy
  class << self
    undef_method :lookup
  end
end

Policy.lookup nil
# => nil
RecordPolicy.lookup
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `lookup' for RecordPolicy:Class
```

Using `#inherited`, we can do

```
class Policy
  def self.lookup(object)
  end
  def self.inherited(sub)
    sub.class_eval do
      class << self
        undef_method :lookup
      end
    end
  end
end

class RecordPolicy < Policy
end

RecordPolicy.lookup
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `lookup' for RecordPolicy:Class
```

Using `sub.class_eval { undef_method :lookup }` won't work, because that will undefine an instance method of `RecordPolicy`. It needs to be invoked on RecordPolicy's eigenclass instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just something to expand on @JimLim's answer.

First, this works because of the difference between what `undef_method` and `remove_method`.

`remove_method` actually deletes the method entirely. `undef_method`, according to the documentation:

> Prevents the **current class** from responding to calls to the named method.

(Emphasis mine).

## But...

If your problem is what you show in the question, I think you're thinking about this wrong. What's wrong about being able to call `RecordPolicy.lookup`? It might be useless, but it follows the Principle of Least Astonishment. The `Policy` class is the right place for this method, but if you implement it something like this:

```
def self.lookup(obj)
  if(self.superclass == Policy) #It's a subclass, return self
    return self
  else
    #look stuff up
  end
end
```

Nothing is out of place. Just because a method is useless on an object, if it would make sense *language*wise for it to be there, don't mess around with it. Ruby gives you great power to change these things for clarity, not to break language conventions and make confusing, unintuitive classes and subclassing behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I really appreciate your perspective on POLA. Now I'm mulling this: I think of the lookup method as an implementation detail. It is public because other objects in the related module call it, but preference is code outside the module not use the class except to inherit from it. So, in this case, which is less astonishing: a class method gets inherited but should really be ignored by the subclass, a class method gets inherited but it behaves differently when it is inherited, or a subclass has a method removed which it doesn't need?

Comment: @andrew: well, the least astonishing is ac tallying probably number 2" because users of the library/whatever are only going to understand that it should be ignored if they read all the documentation, and it's in the documentation. If it behaves in an expected manner, even when calling it is useless, I think that is the least "astonishing".